# No network interface presented during install

Tags: wireless, system-installation, usb

I am installing **Ubuntu Server 18.04** to a **Lenovo Thinkpad 1208-11iAP** (Model 81A4, if that's important) with 2 gig of memory and a 64g hard drive. The installation medium is a usb thumb drive. I am using an **Iogear Model#GWU627** wifi usb dongle, which has previously worked with two other computers.

The installation runs correctly until **Step 4/9**, "*Configure at least one interface this server can use to talk to other machines, and which preferably provides sufficient access for updates.*"

There is **no network interface to configure**; no list and just plan space on the screen.

If I select "Done" anyway, I get the error message "*Network configuration times out; please verify your settings.*"

I have read about using dongles for network access so that Linux installations can be completed and the wifi set up. But I have not been able to find an instance when the dongle wasn't recognized and offered up for configuration.

The Iogear dongle has a *green power light* and a blinking *green WLAN light*. I can ping it  at static address **192.168.1.252**, so I conclude that it is working and properly configured. Removing and reconnecting the usb dongle does nothing. Is there a way I can skip the network connections step (#4), or get the Thinkpad to recognize the dongle?

One last detail: when I switch the dongle and the usb thumb drive, the installation works (up to step 4), so it isn't a bad usb port.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77659/discussion-on-question-by-john-r-woodward-no-network-interface-presented-during).

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you do not have a Cat5 connection port, at all, and that your device is wifi-only, I have to assume that you're using a wifi connection to connect to this 'bridge' (yes, these are called ethernet-to-wireless 'bridges' in some tech corners).

Therefore, I have to assume you are attempting to use Wifi to connect to this dongle/device.  If you are not using Ethernet and are instead trying a Wifi connection, then this answer still stands.

This said, if you are trying to use wifi-only, this device isn't going to work that way, it needs a LAN / Ethernet connection to work properly, so you are still stuck with the same problem.  (Even if you're trying to connect to a standard wifi network, too)

---

The Server installer ISO generally does not come equipped to work with wireless networks.  As such, you typically need to do a Server install with an Ethernet connection or a USB Ethernet adapter, then install network manager, its command line component, wpa2supplicant, and others.

As such, whether your wireless dongle is working or not, the Ubuntu Server ISO is typically not equipped to handle it.  You would need to do an Ubuntu Desktop install to install the system with a wifi adapter, as the Desktop ISOs come equipped with the requisite software (network manager, wpa2supplicant, etc.) to handle wifi connections.

---

You can, however, use the Desktop ISO to install Ubuntu, and then install Apache or whatever server-specific packages you wish to the OS afterwards.  This way, you can have all the GUI bits which will help handle Wifi (network manager, etc.), while also still running the server applications.

I personally have this as the case in certain types of hardware, so I can vouch that it works (though I typically prefer to run Server which doesn't have the GUI's overhead memory and resource costs if I'm running a server).

Comment: NO. This is not a wifi dongle. This is an ethernet-to-wifi dongle. I have never seen that before. It plugs into the ethernet socket and the wifi card connects to the AP.

Comment: @solsTiCe Impossible by OP's comments.  They don't have a Cat5 jack so therefore no LAN port.  Which suggests they're trying to wifi-connect to this device.

Comment: This is more likely an *ideapad 120S-11iAP* which comes with no rj45 plug.

Comment: @solsTiCe Let's wait for the OP to respond to comments before we continue discussing further.  If it doesn't have an Ethernet port then OP can't use Server.  Not without buying a USB Ethernet adapter to take the place of the "wifi" for the purposes of installation only (and those are pretty cheap...)

Comment: This is the Ideapad 120S-11iap, with no rj45 plug. The wifi dongle is in a usb port. The dongle is connected to the wifi LAN; I can ping it. My question is limited to why it doesn't show up as a network interface option in Step 4, when, according to what others have done, and posted, the dongle is visible and can be configured. My understanding from what I have read is that if I have a working install with an Internet connection, I can obtain the drivers for the built-in wifi -- the dongle is a temporary solution.

Comment: @JohnR.Woodward for the reasons in my answer: the Server ISO is not equipped to handle Wifi Connections with your wifi dongle.  However, the 'dongle' you indicated in your question is not a dongle.  You need a USB Ethernet adapter to 'configure' the network with, on an Ethernet line, because the Server ISO doesn't *support* wifi dongles or connectivity on its installer.

Comment: I read your answer last night and combined it with some thing my phone guru told me (also last night, if I'd been able to get him on the phone earlier, I never would have posted). Since all I wanted to do was play around with some LAMP programming, and the LAMP stack will install to Desktop, I switched to installing Desktop. If I had done a little more research, In wouldn't have bothered the elders with my newbie confusion/overreaching. Thanl you, everybody.

Comment: @JohnR.Woodward Glad to hear it.  I just added that bit to my question because it came to me before I saw your comment, glad to hear that that is being corroborated by others heh.  Good luck going forward with getting it working :)